# Unable to install settings module

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my code, there is an import at the top:

```
from settings import Settings
```

I need to install the settings module but whenever I try to install it, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement settings (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for settings
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: what `setting` module are you trying to import? based on the error log it says that `settings` pypi module does not exists so you can't install it. By any means are you trying to load django settings?

Answer (score 0):

Which pip module did you use there is few settings modules python-settings or Djangosettings

Comment: I'm using pip 19.3.1

Comment: I mean the module  which  contains the settings class.